# CSS Padding vs Margin for Typography with Backgrounds in Parent vs Child

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

I understand the container model fully, but I'm wondering about best practice in my current case.

Here is the site http://dev.permi.co/ - based on _s wordpress theme.

Here's part of the HTML:

```
<div class='content-area'>
    <div class='entry-header'>
    <h1 class='entry-title'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the margins/padding currently in place:

```
.content-area {padding:10px;}
h1.entry-title {background-color:#111111;}
```

All I have is padding on the parent div. This way I only have to add padding once, which seems right from what I can find: [CSS, nested divs & margins vs. padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419519/css-nested-divs-margins-vs-padding)

However, they mention with Backgrounds, you should perhaps use padding on the individual elements instead.

I do want the padding around the background color, so the color doesn't extend all the way.

However, I ALSO need padding inside the H1 so it's not right next to the gutter.

Will I need to remove the parent padding, and add padding to all child elements? Then add a margin to this H1 as well?

If so, are there any performance or compatibility concerns? I'm pretty new with CSS, I'm more dev-oriented.

Comment: What's your question..?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow submitted without being ready. Hit enter after typing a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the best solution is to add the **padding** into the **child objects**...
Or add **background-color** to the **parent object**...